# how to load Image in apex.execute

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, callout

Wants some information about the image loading while my process is happening.

Actually I m calling a callout on Button click , for that I have used

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
var url = parent.location.href;
sforce.apex.execute("ConsumeCallout","ConsumeData",{ObjName:"Contact",ConName:"{!Contact.Id}",MobileNumber:"{!Contact.MobilePhone}",PhoneNumber:"{!Contact.Phone}"});
```

But the result comes in after 4-5 secoonds . So I want to show a loading image in the mean time.
Can someone suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call the sforce.apex.execute, use javascript to show an image.
I would suggest to use a javascript library like jQuery.
Then you can do something like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
var url = parent.location.href;
$('the id of the element you want to change').html('<img src="image_url_here" />');
sforce.apex.execute("ConsumeCallout","ConsumeData",{ObjName:"Contact",ConName:"!Contact.Id}",MobileNumber:"{!Contact.MobilePhone}",PhoneNumber:"{!Contact.Phone}"});
```

If you use the element that is going to be updated by sforce.apex.execute it will disappear when that gets updated.
But for a full answer you would have to post some more code (especially the html)